# How to override a class with constructor on a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, overriding

I'm trying to override a plugin class on a WordPress plugin.
Here is the original plugin class :

```
class WCV_Vendor_Dashboard
{
       /**
        * __construct()
        */
        function __construct()
        {
            add_shortcode( 'wcv_shop_settings', array( $this, 'display_vendor_settings' ) );
            add_shortcode( 'wcv_vendor_dashboard', array( $this, 'display_vendor_products' ) );

            add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'check_access' ) );
            add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'save_vendor_settings' ) );
        }

        public function save_vendor_settings(){
               //some codes here
        }
 }
```

Here is what I'm trying (in functions.php), but it doesn't work :

```
$wcv_vendor_dashboard = new WCV_Vendor_Dashboard();
global $wcv_vendor_dashboard;
remove_action( 'init', array( $wcv_vendor_dashboard , 'save_vendor_settings' ) );
```

How to remove it correctly and how to create the replacement?

**Additional info:**
I did similar thing on the WooCommerce core. When I want to override a class / function, I use this (for example):

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', array( 'WC_Form_Handler', 'save_account_details' ) );
function new_save_account_details() {
  //custom code here
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'new_save_account_details' );
```

It's working properly on WooCommerce core. I tried something similar on WCV_Vendor_Dashboard but it doesn't work.

Comment: Define child class and instead `WCV_Vendor_Dashboard` then override `save_account_details` with `new_save_account_details`

Comment: can you please be more specific? maybe you can do me a favor to give little example how to do it? thanks!

Comment: I think @htmlbrewery is speaking about https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes with which you can create your own `functions.php` that will override the original one if there are function in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it was working with woocommerce, but it does not work in this case?

When you attach a function on to a specific action, WoredPress creates unique id for that callback and stores that in global `$wp_filter` array ( in fact, it was an array before, but now it is an object ). For object method callbacks ( like `array( $this, 'save_vendor_settings' )` ), the id is generated with `spl_object_hash` php function. For the above example,

```
spl_object_hash( $this ) . 'save_vendor_settings'
```

, and it looks like `000000001c0af63f000000006d7fe83asave_vendor_settings`.

To "legally" remove the object method with `remove_action()` you will need to have access to the original object that was used to attach the function in the first place. If the object exists in global namespace:

```
global $wcv;
remove_action( 'init', array( $wcv, 'save_vendor_settings' ) );
```

Creating another class instance will not work because the generated id is unique for each object, even if they are instances of the same class.

In the case of WooCommerce I guess it was about static class methods. Different logic is used to generate the ids for static class methods, functions and static method callbacks are just returned as strings. For your example it would be:

```
'WC_Form_Handler' . '::' . 'save_account_details'
```

You see why it works for one case, but not for the other.

There is a hack to replace functions attached by replacing them directly in global `$wp_filter` object, but it's not 100% reliable. Since we do not have access to the original object, we can only filter `$wp_filter` by the name of the function, if there are identical names for the same action it will replace wrong handlers.

```
global $wp_filter;
foreach ( $wp_filter['init']->callbacks as $priority => &$callbacks ) {

    foreach ( $callbacks as $id => &$callback ) {

        if ( substr( $id, -strlen( 'save_vendor_settings' ) ) === 'save_vendor_settings' ) {
            // replace the callback with new function
            $callback['function'] = 'new_save_vendor_settings';
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it will work, greetings.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation. it works! I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example for child class

```
class WCV_Vendor_Dashboard_Child extends WCV_Vendor_Dashboard
{
   /**
    * __construct()
    */
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function new_save_vendor_settings(){
           //some codes here
    }
}
```

Comment: okay..thanks! I have implement your code on my functions.php, but now my question is : how to override `save_account_details` with `new_save_account_details` ?

Comment: `save_account_details` has been override with `new_save_account_details` You can use like that `add_action( 'template_redirect', array('WCV_Vendor_Dashboard_Child', 'new_save_account_details' ));`

Comment: I'm sorry but I still puzzled here. how could it has been override if I never `remove_action` the `save_account_details` ? I tried to add `add_action( 'init', array('WCV_Vendor_Dashboard_Child', 'new_save_vendor_settings' ));` after the child class but it doesn't work.